# Mediawiki JSON response: retrieving thumbnail of each category members

Tags: android, json, mediawiki, wikipedia

I am creating a project with Mediawiki and have added 150 members in a category. I need to retrieve the JSON with thumbnails of each category members to use it in my application.

But unfortunately Im not able to retrieve thumbnails of all the category members in that category. Only 48 members are displaying url for thumbnails in the category even though the images are properly added in the website as added for those 48 members.

What mistake am i doing which makes this error in my response in JSON from the queries.

Example of query:

> ```
> http://example.org/api.php?gcmlimit=max&action=query&gcmtitle=Category%3AName&pilimit=max&prop=pageimages&pithumbsize=100&generator=categorymembers&format=json&continue=
> ```

URL above is just a example to display the queries i have used for retrieving the json file response.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is the correct update in url for retrieving proper json with thumbnail of all category members

Comment: I have checked adding new category members and images in the project page and verified.

Comment: You might wanna check the various [configuration settings](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-PageImages/blob/master/extension.json#L37-L94) for PageImages which might exclude some thumbnails.

Comment: @Tgr how to increase the pageImage number

Comment: i dint find how to change that. when i checked through API sandbox testing. It showed 50 limit

Comment: i need to get the thumbnails somehow

Comment: See [query continuation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Continuing_queries).

Comment: But i need to retrieve all list togther into my application

Comment: Can u post a url example pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me and I succeeded.

You can increase limit of thumbnails url retrieval in JSON using pageImages query

You will have to go to the extension where you have installed the this extension.

Inside that there will be a php file named APIQueryPageImages.php in include folder.
Inside the php folder there is a function "getAllowedParams()" change the Values defined there to necessary values , as shown below:

```
 public function getAllowedParams() {
                return array(
                        'prop' => array(
                                ApiBase::PARAM_TYPE => array( 'thumbnail', 'name', 'original' ),
                                ApiBase::PARAM_ISMULTI => true,
                                ApiBase::PARAM_DFLT => 'thumbnail|name',
                        ),
                        'thumbsize' => array(
                                ApiBase::PARAM_TYPE => 'integer',
                                APiBase::PARAM_DFLT => 50,
                        ),
                        'limit' => array(
                                ApiBase::PARAM_DFLT => 1,
                                ApiBase::PARAM_TYPE => 'limit',
                                ApiBase::PARAM_MIN => 1,
                                ApiBase::PARAM_MAX => 500, //Here you can change the limit of value for user which was by default "50"
                                ApiBase::PARAM_MAX2 => 600,  ////Here you change the limit of value for bots which was by default "100"
                        ),
                        'continue' => array(
                                ApiBase::PARAM_TYPE => 'integer',
                                /** @todo Once support for MediaWiki < 1.25 is dropped, just use ApiBase::PARAM_HELP_MSG directly */
                                defined( 'ApiBase::PARAM_HELP_MSG' ) ? ApiBase::PARAM_HELP_MSG : '' => 'api-help-param-continue',
                        ),
                );
        }
```

Comment: @Tgr : check this solution